# PHP insert json object without main key

Tags: php, json

I am struggled at this point.
I am using the script for inserting/updating website languages.

The main structure of the JSON file looks like this

```
{
  "English": {
      "shortcode": "EN"
  }
}
```

Here is a sample of the code I am using to insert a language into my JSON file

```
$data['french'] = $_POST;
array_push($json, $data);
$jsonData = json_encode($json, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
file_put_contents(__DIR__.'/../files/lg.json', $jsonData);
```

But when I insert a new record into my JSON file new key appends in my JSON file and it looks like this,

```
{
  "English": {
      "shortcode": "EN"
  },

  "0": {
    "French": {
        "shortcode": "FR"
    }
  }
}
```

So my question is how can I insert a new record but to not insert the key "0", "1"..

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Replace the first two lines with just: `$json['French'] = $_POST;`

Comment: what is the `var_dump()` for `$_POST` and `$data`?

Comment: Do you have any good reason to use [`array_push()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php)?

Comment: the var_dump() data is "shortcode" => "FR", all data is obtained from POST form

Comment: I am using array_push to insert the gained data from the form and insert it into an array and then update the file contents of the JSON file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only have to make $json[key] = value

`$json['French'] = $_POST;`

If it does not exist it is added, otherwise it is updated

Comment: Thank you because of your help I found where was my issue! :)

Answer (score 0):

It seems the $_POST is an array.
So you are pushing an array onto the $json array

Try this:

```
$json = $json + $_POST;
$jsonData = json_encode($json, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
file_put_contents(__DIR__.'/../files/lg.json', $jsonData);
```